# Проблема с изображениями в html

Tags: html, css, изображения

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно в html центрировать изображение. 
Мне нужно сделать три фотографии, слева, справа и по центру. А под ними текст. Если с первыми двумя все получается, то изображение по центру вставать совсем не хочет. 
Макет, которого нужно добиться прикреплен.  [image: Вот макет, которого нужно добиться.]

Собственно, вопрос также в тему: как присвоить этим изображениям разные имена, чтобы потом в css редактировать отдельно каждую?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот самый современный способ , поддержка 97%

```css
.flex{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-around;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.item{
  padding:10px;
}
.item img{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur odit officiis nulla eum  </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur odit officiis nulla eum </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur odit officiis nulla eum </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А за что здесь отвечает flex? выходит, все три картинки и все три абзаца заключены в блок flex? Верно?

Answer (score -2):

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://im0-tub-by.yandex.net/i?id=a2e5ef4b39ec7ee1eb73dae5d2fb5ef3&n=13" alt="">
<p>asdasdasd</p>
</div>
<div>
<img src="https://im0-tub-by.yandex.net/i?id=a2e5ef4b39ec7ee1eb73dae5d2fb5ef3&n=13" alt="">
<p>asdasdasdas</p>
</div>
<div>
<img src="https://im0-tub-by.yandex.net/i?id=a2e5ef4b39ec7ee1eb73dae5d2fb5ef3&n=13" alt="">
<p>afsadfdasfsdadf</p>
</div>
```